# Use DrawingBrush in non-XAML app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, xaml

Is it possible to convert a WPF [`DrawingBrush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Media.DrawingBrush);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) to a normal Windows Forms `Brush` so that it can be used on normal Windows Forms instead of XAML / WPF?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. WPF and Windows Forms have a whole ecosystem of painting and they are not comparable. In the end they are still using the Windows API to draw, but that is about it.

There are some tools though that can convert some WPF brush types to the Windows Forms ones.